# Finding smallest range to which at least one number belong from every list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have n number of unsorted lists. And I want to find the minimum range to which at least one number belongs from every list.

Example:
n = 3

List 1 : 9  10  5  20

List 2 : 2  20 9

List 3 : 1  12

The solution to this is (9, 12).

So how to calculate this range in minimum time complexity?
Also, can it be done without sorting the lists?

Comment: @MooingDuck The range (9, 1) is empty and the range (1, 9) is larger than the range (9,12).

Comment: @MooingDuck but it is not minimal

Comment: Generally speaking, there're could be more than one solution e.g. add 23 to List 3, then you get (20,23) which is minimal.

Comment: oh, I misread, I was looking for a minimum _set_.  My bad.

Comment: @tmlai: you are correct. So can we find all the ranges if exist?

Comment: (and yes, in the worst case for comparison models, you essentially do have to sort)

Answer (score 3):

With sorting:

1. Sort all lists. Construct a set X that contains leftmost points of each list. This is your first candidate inrerval. Note its length.
2. Remove the leftmost point of X, note which list it comes from. Add the next point from the same list so that X again contains points from all lists. Note the new length. Rinse, repeat.

Without sorting: no idea.

Comment: Well that is so much simpler than my idea!

Comment: this is `O(K*N)`, then? (K list of N items)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I think that would be `O(n*k*log k)` in his terms.

Comment: @njzk2 I think that would be `O(n*k*log k)` if you have `n` lists of `k` points each. You need to remove the leftmost element, this is a priority queue and it requires `O(log k)` per element removal.

Comment: @njzk2 Actually I think it can be done without the priority queue in `O(n*k)` (not including sorting) with a very simple data structure.

Comment: @n.m. : thanks for your answer but I am not sure if I understood completely because I am not arriving to a solution for many cases. Specially when to stop this algorithm. I will really appreciate if you can just give a small example and work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt know if this idea is *optimal*, but it's the first thing that comes to my mind.  Start by sorting the sets:

```
5 9 10 20
2 9 20
1 12
```

To start, we find the minimum "ranges" for just the first list.  This is easy, because it's exactly the same as the first list:

```
(5) (9) (10) (20)  possible minimum ranges for only the first list
```

First we mark each of these as "clean" `*`.

```
(5*) (9*) (10*) (20*)
```

Then we iterate over the second list.  For each element, if it's in an existing range, we move on.  Otherwise, we "merge" it with the single next smaller and single next larger range from the preceeding row, and mark those ranges as dirty.  When merging the list `2 3` with the range `(5)`, that produces the ranges `(2,5)` and `(3,5)` both.

```
2 -> (2,5) (9*) (10*) (20*) There is no range smaller than 2, so it only merges with (5)
9 -> (2,5) (9) (10*) (20*) Already in a range, just mark it as dirty.
20 -> (2,5) (9) (10*) (20) Already in a range, just mark it as dirty.
```

Then delete the clean ranges, and any lists that are supersets of any adjacent list.

```
(2,5) (9) (20)
```

And again for the third list:

```
1 -> (1,5) (9*) (20*)  Extends the (2,5) range
12 -> (1,5) (9,12) (12,20) Note the 12 merges with the (9) and the (20)
delete clean and superset ranges: (1,5) (9,12) (12,20)
```

You're left with "small" ranges where each list has an element in that range.  Simply find the smallest

(1,5) -> size of 5
   (9,12) -> size of 4
   (12,20) -> size of 20

Since `(9,12)` is the smallest, it is the answer.

Comment: in the third list while iterating through 12, why did you leave (9*)?

Comment: The `12 ->` temp merged the 12 into the `(10)` ranage and the `(20)` range.  The removal of clean ranges is the next line.  (Did I understand your question correctly)?

Comment: with second list, why `2 -> (2,5) (9*) (10*) (20*)` and not `2 -> (2,5) (2,9) (2,10) (2,20)` ? (I would assume you'd keep only the smallest range, but how do you prove you are not discarding a list that could be best later?)

Comment: in particular, consider the lists [2, 10], [5], [8]. The best range is [5,10]. wouldn't your algorithm go `(2), (10); (2,5); (2,8)`?

Comment: @njzk2: "we "merge" it with the ranges above and below, and mark those ranges as dirty"  so the first list would indeed be `(2)(10)`, but the second list would be `(2,5)(5,10)` and then the third list would be `(2,8)(5,10)`.

Comment: @njzk2: You could, but it's unnecessary.  It's only necessary to merge it with the single next smaller and single next larger list.

Comment: ok, so merge implies `single next smaller and single next larger`.

Comment: but that does not work for the `9`. in the third list, the `10` seems to magically reappear? isn't it deleted as `clean`?

Comment: @njzk2:  Whoops! Good catch!  (How did I not notice I had arrived at the wrong answer)

Comment: (which probably isn't really an issue since the actual result is 9-12, the 10 is probably a typo from copying the previous line)

Comment: also, what would happen if I had these lists : [4, 10], [2,3], [5] ? the expected result is `[3, 5]`, but wouldn't the [2,3] part expand the (4) list to (2,4) ? or split it into (3,4) and (2,4) ? or the (2,4) is not useful since if there is a 2 later it will appear anyway?

Comment: `(4)(10)`, then `(2,4)(3,4)(10)`, then `(2,4)(3,5)(5,10)`.  I hadn't thought about it, but you're right that you can't just merge the 3 into that `(2,4)`.  However, the `(2,4)` could be dropped since it's a superset of `(3,4)`.  Sadly, I'm no longer convinced that this algorithm always finds the minimum spans...

Comment: i do think it works, the specific cases of merging must be consider. probably something with a set accepting only on item on each side, possibly splitting.